# How to determine the currency code of a given stock using libraries in R?

Tags: r, quantmod

I am currently working with quantmod library in R. Using quantmod, I can get the prices of the required indexes, stocks and equities from yahoo finance. Some of these asset classes are in Canadian dollar and some are in USD. Is it possible to get the names of these indexes and their corresponding currency code using R.

```
Name of Index                           Currency code
S&P/TSX Composite index                      CAD
Dow Jones Industrial Average                 USD
```

Comment: I don't think `getSymbols` or any other method in `quantmod` gets this information . But I'd wonder what purpose currency information will serve in case of market indices. An index's absolute value  will only be comparable with its own historical value.  Such info may be useful in case of individual stocks though. In that case the symbols from different markets have different suffixes on yahoo and a lookup table can be created to get currency

Comment: sorry, my bad,i get what purpose such a comparison would serve. But the only way of getting the info AFAIK is either to scrap yahoo page for that index or create a lookup table (which should be doable because there would only be a limited number of indices and their symbols will have to be known beforehand to fetch the data )

Comment: Thank you. I will go with scrapper. lol

Comment: yeah, scrape it :-)